# Can't see my NFT in Coinbase Wallet on Ropsten

Tags: wallets, erc-721, coinbase, nft

I have created the following ERC721 contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC721/ERC721PausableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721PausableUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable {
  // keep the order of Status
  enum Status { Start, End}
  mapping (uint256 => Status) private status;
  string private constant MY_URI = "www.abc.com/metadata/start.json";
  
  function initialize() initializer public {
    __ERC721_init_unchained("MyNFT", "MNFT");
    __Ownable_init_unchained();
  }

  function mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
    _mint(to, tokenId);
    status[tokenId] = Status.Start;
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, MY_URI);
  }
.
.
.
```

And I've tried the same with a plain-vanilla ERC721 as well:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721 {
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC721(name_, symbol_) public {
    }

    function mint(address holder, uint256 tokenId) public {
      _safeMint(holder, tokenId);
    }
}
```

Then on Ropsten I mint a token to my Coinbase Wallet address (Ropsten). However, I can't see my ERC721 under "Collectibles" in the Coinbase Wallet, although I can see in in the console. Does anyone have an advice how to make the ERC721 visible in Coinbase Wallet? ERC20 tokens I can see.
The same problems applies for both ERC721 contract version, for the upgradeable as well as for the plain-vanilla ERC721.

Is something special required for Coinbase wallets?

Answer (score 0):

On the Rinkeby network (network id 4) it works. However, token details, such as the tokenid are not displayed. Moreover, the token cannot be moved/transferred.